# Dynamic JSON in Terraform

Tags: terraform

I am using Terraform to Invoke a lambda function, and need to pass an input JSON which includes a list of string values.

```
 data "aws_lambda_invocation" "invo6" {
   function_name = "my_function"
   input = <<JSON
   {
     "pairs":[
       {
         "principal":"arn:aws:iam::12345678901:role/myRole", 
         "databases":[
           "my_db_apple", "my_db_banana", "my_db_orange"
          ]
       }
     ] 
  } 
  JSON
}
```

Instead of hard-coding these database names, I want to pull in from a map that already exists elsewhere in my tf files.

```
variable "gluedb_map" {
  type = map(map(string))
  default = {
    "apple" = {             
       description = "my apple db"          
       catalog = ""
       location_uri = "s3://mybucket/"          
       params = ""
    }       
    "banana" = {            
       description = "my banana db"
       catalog = ""
       location_uri = "s3://anotherpath/"
       params = "" 
    }
```

I tried swapping out the 'databases' code for this :

```
input = <<JSON
    {
        "pairs":[
             {
                "principal":"arn:aws:iam::12345678901:role/myRole", 
                ${jsonencode("databases": [for each in var.gluedb_map : "my_db_${each}"], )}
            }
        ]
    } 
    JSON
```

but i then get error :
A comma is required to separate each function argument from the next.

Can anyone spot where I'm going wrong ?
Thanks

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the example input and then the output you're expecting from that input?

Comment: Added details of the map containing the db names. Also expanded code of my failed code.  The required output is the first code section, where I have hard coded the db names - i am trying to recreate this but populating from a map instead of hard-coding. Hope clearer ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're just interested in accessing the keys of the map then you can use the [`keys` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/keys.html) to return a list of keys. You can then combine that with [`formatlist`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/formatlist.html) to interpolate each list item with a string.

I'd also recommend using a HCL map for the wider data structure and then encoding to JSON rather than trying to JSON encode a section of it and having to mangle things to get it in a suitable shape.

A fully worked example then looks something like this:

```
variable "gluedb_map" {
  type = map(map(string))
  default = {
    "apple" = {             
       description = "my apple db"          
       catalog = ""
       location_uri = "s3://mybucket/"          
       params = ""
    }       
    "banana" = {            
       description = "my banana db"
       catalog = ""
       location_uri = "s3://anotherpath/"
       params = "" 
    }
  }
}

output "json" {
  value = jsonencode({
    pairs: [
      {
        principal = "arn:aws:iam::12345678901:role/myRole"
        databases = formatlist("my_db_%s", keys(var.gluedb_map))
      }
    ]
  })
}
```

Applying this will output the following:

```
json = {"pairs":[{"databases":["my_db_apple","my_db_banana"],"principal":"arn:aws:iam::12345678901:role/myRole"}]}
```

Comment: So you just copy pasted the answer from Tasos (posted 2 hours earlier) and added water to it?

Comment: @nickolay.laptev I'm not sure what you mean here? It uses some of the same functions but this answer has a slightly different approach to get there and also explains it in more depth. If you don't think it adds anything then you are welcome to downvote this answer and upvote the other answer but I personally think this answer adds enough to be more useful than the other answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use [keys](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/keys.html), [formatlist](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/formatlist.html) and [join](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/join.html) to get:

```
${jsonencode("databases": [join("," , formatlist("my_db_%s", keys(var.gluedb_map))  )}
```